# Ldap User - Group Sync

Tags: ldap, openldap, sunone

I'm using Sun Directory server v5.2.

```
I have three attributes: designation, role.
I am using a tool using which when i create a create/modify user entry with designation filled, a unique member is added to a group 'Members'.
```

Now, there are circumstances where

```
Scenario1:
* Creating/ Modifying user entry is not done via the tool and so unique member for this user entry is not added to the group  'Members'.

Scenario2:
* When user the designation attribute is deleted, group entry is not deleted.
```

This is causing inconsistency in the users and the group.

How can i resolve this?

Thanks,
Sash.

Comment: Is the referential integrity plugin being used?

Comment: @TerryGardner No. It is not being used and i do no think it will solve the both scenarios.